# Count network interfaces in Bash

Tags: bash, ifconfig

I want to count the number of entries starting with the string "**tun**" that I get as output of the command `ifconfig`.

For example, if this is my output, I want to count to be 2. I tried to play around with `grep`, but it is still not solved.

```
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.0.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:16:73:86:ba  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s31f6: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xa1300000-a1320000

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 905  bytes 80293 (80.2 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 905  bytes 80293 (80.2 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 00.00.00.00  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.105.77
        inet6 ::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 438  bytes 52174 (52.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 457  bytes 33911 (33.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun1: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 0.0.0.0  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.104.61
        inet6 ::  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 10  bytes 584 (584.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: This is a work order, not a question. Aren't any research or (demonstrated) own attempts required?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible using either a combination of `grep` and `wc`, or using `awk`

**First approach**, using `grep`:

```
ifconfig | grep "^tun" | wc -l
```

This will pipe the output of `ifconfig` through grep, match all lines starting with the string `tun` (this is accomplished using the "anchor" indicator `^`), and then use `wc` to count the lines which `grep` output as matched.

**As pointed out** by  @schaiba, it is even possible without resorting to `wc` by virtue of `grep`'s `-c` option, which will count all matched lines by itself:

```
ifconfig | grep -c "^tun"
```

**Second approach**, using `awk`:

```
ifconfig | awk 'BEGIN {tuns=0}; /^tun/ {tuns++}; END {print tuns}'
```

This will pipe the output to `awk`. The `awk` program, enclosed between single quotes `' ... '`, does the following:

- at the beginning (`BEGIN { ... }`), initialize an internal varible `tuns`, which we will use for book-keeping, as 0
- in the main loop, for every line encountered that starts with the string `tun` (indicated by the regular expression `/^tun/`), increase the counter `tuns`
- after the input is finished, (`END { ... }`), output the resulting value of `tuns`

Comment: This is a very good and informative answer. Thank you @AdminBee! If you are still not getting the correct answer, there is the possibility of white space in front of the `tun`. (There _shouldn't_ be, but I've see lots of weird stuff). To adjust for that, in the grep command you can add `[.space. .tab.].asterisk.` between the `^` and the `tun`. Or, some versions of Linux allow `[[:blank:]].*` instead.

Comment: Be careful ! This method does what you ask, but it could be that this is not what you actually mean: `ifconfig` only shows configured interfaces. You might be interested in all interfaces in which case you need `ifconfig -a`

Answer (score 12):

You probably don't need `ifconfig` (or `ip`) for this. The interfaces are listed in `/sys/class/net`:

```
% ls /sys/class/net
eth0  lo  tun0  tun1  tun2  wlan0
```

So, you can count the directories there, with something like:

```
$ printf "%s\n" /sys/class/net/tun* | wc -l
3
```

Comment: Or better `(shopt -s nullglob; set -- /sys/class/net/tun*; echo "$#")` or with `zsh`: `(){echo $#} /sys/class/net/tun*(N)`

Comment: Yet another method using sysfs: `for device in /sys/class/net/tun* ; do echo $device ; done | wc -l`. (But in "real life" I would also use ifconfig, see AdminBee's answer)

Comment: (In real life, I've often had to deal with docker images, at least some of which don't have `ifconfig` or `ip` installed.)

Comment: Note that your naive version prints 1 instead of 0 when there are no `tun` interfaces.

Comment: Yes, the method of counting here isn't perfect. However, what I wanted to show here is that instead of parsing `ifconfig` or `ip` output, the problem can be reduced to counting entries in a directory, which is a far more common problem, with plenty of methods in many languages.